LLMGraphTransformer.convert_to_graph_documents(documents) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'
from langchain_core.documents import Document

text = """
Marie Curie, born in 1867, was a Polish and naturalised-French physicist and chemist who conducted pioneering research on radioactivity.
She was the first woman to win a Nobel Prize, the first person to win a Nobel Prize twice, and the only person to win a Nobel Prize in two scientific fields.
Her husband, Pierre Curie, was a co-winner of her first Nobel Prize, making them the first-ever married couple to win the Nobel Prize and launching the Curie family legacy of five Nobel Prizes.
She was, in 1906, the first woman to become a professor at the University of Paris.
"""
documents = [Document(page_content=text)]
graph_documents = llm_transformer.convert_to_graph_documents(documents)
print(f"Nodes:{graph_documents[0].nodes}")
print(f"Relationships:{graph_documents[0].relationships}")---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-0a6a66b2d25f> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 """
      9 documents = [Document(page_content=text)]
---> 10 graph_documents = llm_transformer.convert_to_graph_documents(documents)
     11 print(f"Nodes:{graph_documents[0].nodes}")
     12 print(f"Relationships:{graph_documents[0].relationships}")

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_experimental/graph_transformers/llm.py in process_response(self, document)
    593             nodes_set = set()
    594             relationships = []
--> 595             parsed_json = self.json_repair.loads(raw_schema.content)
    596             for rel in parsed_json:
    597                 # Nodes need to be deduplicated using a set

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'

I am using the Colab Notebooks environment, Llm uses the HuggingFaceH4/starchat2-15b-v0.1 API
I found a similar issue on GitHub--https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/21482

This is probably because you are using a model other than GPT4.
For this to work with some other models, you need to pass your own prompt to the LLMGraphTransformer (reference)
Something like this:
from langchain_experimental.graph_transformers.llm import UnstructuredRelation, examples

system_prompt = """
You are a data scientist working for a company that is building a knowledge graph database. 
Your task is to extract information from data and convert it into a knowledge graph database.
Provide a set of Nodes in the form [head, head_type, relation, tail, tail_type].
It is important that the head and tail exists as nodes that are related by the relation. If you can't pair a relationship with a pair of nodes don't add it.
When you find a node or relationship you want to add try to create a generic TYPE for it that describes the entity you can also think of it as a label.
You must generate the output in a JSON format containing a list with JSON objects. Each object should have the keys: "head", "head_type", "relation", "tail", and "tail_type".
"""

system_message = SystemMessage(content=system_prompt)
parser = JsonOutputParser(pydantic_object=UnstructuredRelation)

human_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template="""
Examples:
{examples}

For the following text, extract entities and relations as in the provided example.
{format_instructions}\nText: {input}""",
    input_variables=["input"],
    partial_variables={
        "format_instructions": parser.get_format_instructions(),
        "node_labels": None,
        "rel_types": None,
        "examples": examples,
    },
)

human_message_prompt = HumanMessagePromptTemplate(prompt=human_prompt)

chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [system_message, human_message_prompt]
)

llm_transformer = LLMGraphTransformer(llm=llm, prompt=chat_prompt)


Thank you so much for your feedback . This feature heavily relies on a robust LLM. I’ve noticed that using the HuggingFaceH4/starchat2-15b-v0.1 API doesn’t consistently generate data in JSON format, which has led to the failure of my experiment. Thank you once again .
